# how to sort numbers in even and odd pattern using sort in vim editor

Tags: vim

I want the following pattern in increasing order with odd numbers 1st and then even number like

```
0
2
4
6
1
3
5
```

using `:sort` in vim editor

Answer (score 0):

```
:sort nr /^\d*[02468]$/ | sort nr /^\d*[13579]$/
```